# TableViewCell Appearance only changes the cell's currently in the view

Tags: ios, uilabel, uiappearance

Using UIAppearance, I am changing the Table View Cell's label colour. This works fine but it only colours the cells currently being seen. All the cell's out of the view (not being seen) are still the default colour (black).

In a summary, the method only changes the cell's currently being seen, not the cells out of view (scrolled out of view).

Here is my UIAppearance Code:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[_textLabel class], nil]
 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(204.0f/255.0f) green:(204.0f/255.0f) blue:(204.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
```

Comment: Can you post more code please? Like the part where you call these method for example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a typo here, `_textLabel` must be a `UITableViewCell` not a `UILabel`,

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[YourTableViewCell class], nil]
 setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(204.0f/255.0f) green:(204.0f/255.0f) blue:(204.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
```

You may check reusing cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's a UILabel because the title of the cell is the problem, not the cell background colour.

Comment: It wouldn't matter anyway as _textLabel is part of UITableViewCell

Comment: That's the same thing as I am doing but just calling the UITableViewCell directly

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that The code I'm calling only changes the text color of the cells currently in the viewable area.

Comment: hmm, can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not reusing the cells?

Comment: Nope and Could that be the problem?

Comment: I think so, anyway you have to optimize your cell reusing, it is very important performance-wise also, it is two lines of code dude. One more thing please remove this `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Comment: Hmm, Im still a beginner at this. Mind posting that reuse code?